# Best way to convert current time to seconds in Java

Tags: java, date, time, epoch

I  wanted to get the current time in seconds. I found 3 approaches. But confused which one will be the best option.

```
long usingEpochSecond = Instant.now().getEpochSecond();
long usingDate1 = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(new Date().getTime());
long usingDate2 = new Date().getTime()/1000
```

Which one is the best solution? Is there an even better option?

Comment: Only the first one uses the [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html) package and hence is the recommended way.

Comment: Easy: The first one because it does not involve an outdated API (`java.util`).

Comment: Great. thanks @Abra for the quick response :)

Comment: Thanks @deHaar for quick response

Comment: `TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(System.currentTimemills())` is a valid answer too - there’s no real reason to create an `Instant` just to throw it away.

Comment: Sure, all the answers are valid, but OP asked for the *best* solution, and every answer to it is somehow opinion-based ;-)

Comment: Thanks @BoristheSpider. it is a valid point too.

Comment: In any case I recommend you don’t use the `Date` class. It is poorly designed and long outdated. Apart from that use what will be least surprising to those reading your code. You may know them better than I do.